# Uncaught ReferenceError: getAuth is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Self taught coder here. Hopefully I'm explaining the issue adequately.

I'm trying to create some user authentication using firebase. I keep getting an error saying "Line 18:16:  'getAuth' is not defined". I'm confused because I was following a tutorial. I have tried reordering my imports as I read online that might be the reason for the error. For some reason I think my problem is in the config file and how I've initialized everything. I'm new to firebase. Any potential solves would be appreciated.

Here is my firebase.js config

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/storage"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY",
  authDomain: "uploadimg.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "uploadimgofficial",
  storageBucket: "uploadimg.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "MESSENGER_ID",
  appId: "APP_ID",
  measurementId: "MESAUREMENT_ID"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth()

// Init firestore
const db = getFirestore()
export { db }
```

And this is where I'm trying to set up the login page

```
import React from "react";
import "./Login.scss";
import { useState } from "react";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../../firebase"; 



const Login = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const auth = getAuth();  // <------ THIS IS ERROR LINE
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // Signed in 
      const user = userCredential.user;
      console.log(user)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setError(true)
    });

  return (
    <div className="login">
      <form onSubmit={handleLogin} className="login__form">
        <input 
            className="login__email" 
            onChange={e => setNewEmail(e.target.value)} 
            type="email" 
            placeholder="email" />
        <input
```

Comment: You haven't imported getAuth into the file where you use it.  That's required on a per-file basis.

Comment: remove that line, you do not need, you already created the `auth` in the other file.

Comment: I imported getAuth into the file where it's being used and it worked. So weird the tutorial I was watching never did that step! Doug, thank you so much! Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you have imported the `getAuth` function incorrectly.

To fix this, you need to correct the name usage when calling the function.

---

As you have imported `getAuth` as `auth` in the `import` statement at the top of your file, you need to use it as so.

```js
import { auth } from "../../firebase.js";
```

Right now, you are importing the `auth` variable, which is set to the return value of `getAuth`, as defined below in the `firebase.js` file.

```js
// As you are calling the function with '()', you are getting the return value.
export const auth = getAuth();
```

---

To fix this, simply change your function call to `auth`. Also, rename the variable to something other than `auth` to avoid name collisions, and/or confusing naming patterns.

Also, as you are getting and setting the return value of `getAuth` to `auth`, the return value may **not** be a function<sup>1</sup>. In that case, you can't call `auth` with brackets (`()`), as, for instance, it may return an object.

```js
// Change the variable name to what you want.
const userAuth = auth;
```

To check if it is a `string`/`object`/`function`/etc, you can use `typeof` (for checking/debugging; remove this line once done).

```js
console.log(typeof auth); // Should return: 'string' | 'function' | 'object' | ...
```

Depending on the return type, you can change your usage to match it.

---

In conclusion, to fix your issue, you need to correctly use the name (`auth` instead of `getAuth`). Also, make sure to check the return value of `getAuth`, and use it appropriately!

---

*<sup>1</sup> Please correct me in the comments if I am incorrect; the return value is a `function`. In that case, I can remove that part. Thank you for the clarification!*